# Something to view wavefront object files (.OBJ) along with their material files (.MTL)

Tags: gratis, linux, 3d

I need:

- To be able view wavefront object files that are colored according to a wavefront material file.
- The software to work on Linux and ideally be free.

I do not need:

- To modify or manipulate the object
- Save it to another format

Attempts so far:

- Tried installing `meshlab`, but for some reason snap refuses to work. Maybe a Fedora 29 issue, unsure.
- GLC Player doesn't seem to exist. I can't find how to get it on linux anywhere. Maybe it has to be built from source? If so, not sure where to get it.

Answer (score 1):

Blender will do that pretty handily, and of course a whole lot more as well.

[Blender.org](https://www.blender.org/)

Comment: Could you also give an example how this is done in Blender?